Is there a way to temporarily disable auto-join on all Wi-Fi networks and force Wi-Fi to remain disconnected in macOS?
I have a MacBook Pro running macOS 13.6.6 where I frequently turn off Wi-Fi because it has a wired network connection, and I don't want it to try automatically connecting to Wi-Fi networks. However, doing so prevents location services from working, meaning useful features like getting the weather in my current location no longer works.
Since there's likely no way to use location services without Wi-Fi at least being enabled, I'm looking for alternative approaches to accomplishing what I want. So is there a way to temporarily force Wi-Fi not to be connected to any networks, and not auto-join any of its preferred networks? An ideal method would allow me to switch whether it's connecting to networks on or off from a script.

What’s the count of SSID you need to automate? I’m going to assume you have one and only one SSID you’d auto join in this one location where Ethernet is available (or two max, one at home and one at work?)

Yes, currently just two SSIDs, but there could be more in the future.

If you disable Auto Join for those two, and restart while connected to Ethernet , things should work like a charm… (for testing the concept before you attempt to automate it)

In the Network preference pane, Ethernet should have a higher priority than Wi-Fi when it’s connected. If not, you can change the service order so that it does. Then all traffic to addresses that are reachable via Ethernet will go through it. Wi-Fi will be used only for addresses that are only routable  through that network (usually none.) Whether Wi-Fi is auto-joined or not doesn't matter.

Yes! This is the way, then try disabling auto join if needed on just the few networks where you are on Ethernet. It’s always a quick join from the WiFi menu when you pick up your portable. I’ll answer if I can conclusively say there’s no way to do this. My hunch is it’s not easily managed and you’ll just need to be very choosy which SSID you allow to auto join.
